# Displacement size (disp_size) of x86 instructions

Tags: disassembly, assembly, x86, x86-64, capstone

Given the opcode `80 3d 1d b0 09 00 00`.

The corresponding capstone instruction is

```
<CsInsn 0x66a4 [803d1db0090000]: cmp byte ptr [rip + 0x9b01d], 0>
```

and has the following properties (`c_i` being the name of the instruction object)

```
c_i.disp: 0x9b01d
c_i.disp_offset: 0x2
c_i.disp_size 0x4
```

A different instruction

`<CsInsn 0xd3de [66c705714309000000]: mov word ptr [rip + 0x94371], 0>`
has:

```
c_i.disp:         0x94371
c_i.disp_offset:  0x3
c_i.disp_size:    0x2
```

The first two properties make sense to me. But why is the `disp_size` `0x2` and not `0x4`?

Comment: I don't really know the answer, this might be it, but just pointing out the first is operating on `byte` and the second is `word` (2 byte)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a bug, there is an open issue in the Capstone repo that seems to fit: https://github.com/capstone-engine/capstone/issues/1640

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21909)

Comment: Sorry, I've edited to make it clear that I thought this was a bug.